# icCube unary operator for a singe measure

Tags: iccube

I have a parent-child dimension and a fact table that has measures specified for both the children and the parents. The last level of the dimension is also involved in M2M relationships.

If i use regular sum aggregations, the measure values for the parent members are double counted (as expected). I tried changing the Fact Aggregation property of the dimension to "Members Only" but this creates problems with the M2Ms. Is that expected or should I be able to use this property?

I can get the desired result using the unary operator but it seems that the parent's value is always ignored in its own calculation. For example, if my dimension looks like this:

ParentArea1
 -- ChildArea1
 -- ChildArea2

and my fact table has:
**Area,Amount**
ParenArea1, 10
ChildArea1, 6
ChildArea2, 4

then I can apply the UO + to ChildArea1 and ChildArea2 but the value of 10 assigned to ParentArea1 is never used in calculating its own **Amount** regardless of the UO I apply. The end result is correct, I just want to make sure I understand the logic.

Comment: John, could you create a in Memory model so we can base our discussion on it ?

Comment: see model here: https://1drv.ms/u/s!At2q8pB9kiwu-13CiZSDDaeoRE5f and this file has the mdx queries (I'm testing from excel) https://1drv.ms/t/s!At2q8pB9kiwu-1v6VQZqhPMRuw9V  I expected Query1 to return a value for member Area2 but it does not. However, If I replace the UO column in the last 2 rows of the Area table to + then I do get the desired outcome -- just want to make sure this is expected.  I also expected Query2 and Query3 to return the same result but in Query3 returns an empty set. The main difference is that I set FactAggregation to MembersOnly for the AreaMemberOnly Dimension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the 'unary operator' as fact aggregation ([doc](https://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/user_guide/schemas_cubes/facts_aggregation.php)). Leafs are calculated using the sum aggregation and the unary operator is used only for members with children. The 'fact' value of the parent is ignored; it would only make sense to use the parent value if the hierarchy defines 'members only' but it's not done (children value would be twice with members and descendants). It's relatively easy to improve and extend this rollup aggregation, feel free to contact if you need something special.

I've to look a bit more in detail, but I don't see why M2M creates any issue. A M2M makes possible for several member leaves to point to the same row, but this is all.

hope it helps